# send values separated by commas and uses as variables

Tags: php

I have a variable posting to another page and when echoed out, it looks like

```
Acme, Upgrade Site, Kansas
```

I want to separate those by the comma and assign 3 variable like

```
$Company = ‘Acme’; 
$Action = ‘Upgrade Site’; 
$Location = ‘Kansas’;”
```

Comment: Using something like `str_split()` or `explode()` will get the values separated in an array.  You can individually assign them to variables after that.

Comment: You can use the `explode()` function (http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to turn the string into an array of values.  Then you can use the values form the array, or assign them from the array into individual variables.

Comment: `list($company,$action,$location)=explode(',',$mystring);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str= 'Acme, Upgrade Site, Kansas' ;
$arr = explode(',',$str); 

$Company = $arr[0]; 
$Action = $arr[1]; 
$Location = $arr[2];
```

try

Answer (score 0):

So the best bet here I think is probably to use `explode`:

```
// Assume $inputString is your input
$explodedInput = explode(",", $inputString);

// Now, $explodedInput[0] will be Company,
// $explodedInput[1] will be "Upgrade Site", etc...
$Company = $explodedInput[0] //...
```

Comment: There's not much use for `<code>` tags when you're entering code as an answer - if you indent code with four spaces (or use the `{}` button) it's all marked up correctly for you.